# Firebase web codelab: missing app configuration value "appId"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm stuck on [Firebase web codelab page 8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#8), getting the error:

> FirebaseError: Installations: Missing App configuration value: "appId" ...

I think I've followed the instructions. The http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/init.js does not contain such a field:

```
if (typeof firebase === 'undefined') throw new Error('hosting/init-error: Firebase SDK not detected. You must include it before /__/firebase/init.js');
var firebaseConfig = {
  "projectId": "friendlychat-310120",
  "databaseURL": "https://friendlychat-310120.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "friendlychat-310120.appspot.com",
  "locationId": "europe-west3",
  "apiKey": "AIza...vOXg",
  "authDomain": "friendlychat-310120.firebaseapp.com",
  "messagingSenderId": "480343738796"
};
if (firebaseConfig) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

It's not only the error. Reading the messages does not work.

[image]

Comment: If there's a problem with the codelab, please post an issue to GitHub so it can get fixed.  https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-web

Comment: Good point. But there’s no problem - I had simply skimmed through the instructions here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#2 too fast. It clearly states: “Register the app with the nickname Friendly Chat, then check the box next to Also set up Firebase Hosting for this app. Click Register app.”

Answer (score 3):

In [Issue 2287](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2287) there's background for this. Breaking change mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#fcm_1):

> If you are currently using FCM for web and want to upgrade to SDK 7.0.0 or later, you must enable the [FCM Registration API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/fcmregistrations.googleapis.com) for your project in the Google Cloud Console.

I did that:

[image]

In addition, one needs to:

> Please also make sure that projectId, apiKey, appId and messagingSenderId are present in your app config.

The lead for how to reach this is [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2220):

> Ok. Resolved. The `appId` is definitely not the `projectId`. And I have a hard time finding what it is, or how to get it. In order to get the `appId`, you need to create an app registration (android, iOS or web) in the Firebase Console. ...

You likely see this:

[image]

Click the `</>` icon, and the app gets registered. This is enough. Now your `http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/init.js` hosted config object should include also the `.appId` field.

```
  "appId": "1:4803...8796:web:400d...d209",
```

Also - most importantly! - my web codelab app now works!

[image]

This happens with Firebase web codelab. Hopefully they add a mention about the need to register the app (or maybe I just missed it?).

Comment: i have all that and still get this very same error.